# Where I can get jooq and jdbc modules for jooby 2.10.0?

Tags: jdbc, jooq, jooby

I'm trying to use

```
implementation("io.jooby:jooby-jooq:2.10.0") 
implementation("io.jooby:jooby-jdbc:2.10.0")
```

with

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google() 
}
```

but get "Could not find..." gradle message

I see note that artifact was moved at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooby/jooby
but I follow the link and don’t find it there

Where I can get jooq and jdbc modules for jooby 2.10.0?

Comment: I can only find a 1.6.9 version (and earlier) of jooby-jooq and jooby-jdbc (in the org.jooby namespace), which suggests these modules don't exist in 2.x.

Comment: Wehn I look at the docs I can't see any jooby extension anymore. But 1.6.9 is brand new.

Comment: The author answered me on github: "Since 2.x release jooby-jdbc is now jooby-hikari and jooby-jooq wasn't migrated to 2.x"

But the question of how to use jooq with jooby 2.x is still open.

Comment: What do you need a "module" for? Once you have a JDBC connection or data source, you're ready to go, with jOOQ.

Answer (score 0):

The author answered me on github: "Since 2.x release jooby-jdbc is now jooby-hikari and jooby-jooq wasn't migrated to 2.x"